Building TypeScript Node.js App with ESBuild in Monorepo Context fails on Docker but succeeds on local
As the title implies, I am trying to build/bundle a node.js application in Docker, which then give me this error
2.830 /app/packages/api/node_modules/.bin/esbuild: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
2.837 npm error Lifecycle script `build` failed with error:
2.838 npm error code 2
2.838 npm error path /app/packages/api
2.838 npm error workspace @dispono/api@1.0.0
2.838 npm error location /app/packages/api
2.838 npm error command failed
2.838 npm error command sh -c tsc && esbuild dist/index.js --bundle --sourcemap --platform=node --outfile=dist/index.minified

and my Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine AS base

RUN apk update && apk add bash

FROM base AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY packages/database/package.json ./packages/database/
COPY packages/api/package.json ./packages/api/
COPY packages/api/tsconfig.json ./packages/api/
RUN npm ci -w @dispono/database -w @dispono/api

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm run build -w @dispono/api

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY packages/ ./packages/
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/packages/api/dist/ ./dist

COPY run-docker.sh ./run-docker.sh
RUN chmod +x ./run-docker.sh

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "./run-docker.sh" ]

The weird thing is, that the build works locally, both in root (monorepo -- npm workspace) and in the package itself. I was so happy that it worked locally with esbuild, as I've tried many bundler from webpack to rollup. Has this anything to do with the monorepo setup? Any idea/ help appreciated thanks.
Tried:

Building a nodejs app with esbuild.
Applying typescript - Esbuild - Unexpected token '<' on my  tsconfig.json file.

Expected: The app is built and minified and could be serve in a docker container alongside with the database.
Result: Bash syntax error.

Do you have a .dockerignore file on the host that keeps the host's node_modules file out of the image?  I'd wonder that, or if the upstream esbuild script says it uses /bin/sh but actually requires GNU Bash features, and an Alpine-based image won't work because of an unrelated bug.

@DavidMaze Hey thanks for your suggestion. I tried ignoring node_modules as well, but it didn't work. I suspect there are commonjs and esm conflict somewhere in my code. I used alpine based image, because I want to keep it lean, thought adding bash to it in the Dockerfile would solve the problem, but I'd take that into account!
